# Orient objects in same direction across devices

Tags: three.js

I am making a first-person, multiplayer game using Three.js where players' opponents are represented on their screens as airplanes. I need to be able to orient the airplane on the screen of person B in the same direction as the camera of person A so that when person A moves forward, the airplane on the other person's screen moves forward AND faces forward, rather than drifting forward while facing backwards or sideways. I need transmit the orientation information as a JSON object. I tried transmitting the rotation property of the camera and setting the rotation property of the airplane based on that at the other end, but for some reason the airplane does all sorts of strange twists and flips and doesn't face the direction it should. What is the best way to set the orientation of an Object3D so that it faces same direction as the camera on another device?

Answer (score 0):

Camera and Object3D have a method named *lookAt* that rotates them to face the *given direction*. **WARN**: you should calculate the direction, it means:

> (position you want to look at - position of your object).normalize();

Comment: How do I get the position I want to look at? Is there some kind of camera.getLookingPosition() method? I imagine I would need to get some point directly in front of the camera, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The camera has rotation values, form there you can find the direction the camera is looking to. Could you make some drawings explaining better what do you want to achieve? your explanation is a bit intricate...