# Three.js position objects on curve - rotate towards center of circle

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

I'm attempting to create a snazzy VR menu so that when the user looks down the menu items are in a column below camera curved around circle so they look the same and are rotated towards camera.

Here is my attempt thus far
[image]

And a CodePen with the example
http://codepen.io/bknill/pen/BLOwLj?editors=0010

I'm using some code I found that calculates the position

```
   var radius = 60; // radius of the circle
  var height = 60,
      angle = 0,
      step = (Math.PI /2 ) /  menuItems.length;

menuItems.forEach(function(item,index){

    var menuItem = createMenuItem(item.title);
       menuItem.position.y = - Math.round(height/2 + radius * Math.sin(angle));
       menuItem.position.z =  Math.round(height/2 + radius * Math.sin(angle));
      // menuItem.rotation.x =  -Math.round(Math.PI * Math.sin(angle));
    angle += step;
    menu.add(menuItem);

})
```

Which is almost right, the next stage is to get them to rotate in a uniform way towards the camera. Using menuItem.lookAt(camera.position) isn't working - they're not uniform rotation.

child.lookAt(camera.position.normalize()) does this
[image]

Anyone let me know the clever maths I need to get the rotation of the item so they face the camera and look like they're on a curve?

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to have an object facing another object is using [lookAt](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D).

Be aware this method needs a direction vector, not the point where you want it to look at.

> (position you want to look at - position of your object).normalize();

In your case:

```
var dirToLookAt = new THREE.Vector3();
dirToLookAt.subVectors(menuItem.position, camera.position);
// could be: dirToLookAt.subVectors(camera.position, menuItem.position);
dirToLookAt.normalize();
```

Operations based on [Vector3 documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3).

For more info you can read [the last discussion I had about this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379671/orient-objects-in-same-direction-across-devices).

Comment: I'm struggling to implement this and get the desired result. Please could you indicate how you'd use this in the code?

Comment: Just give me the name of one of the objects you want to face the camera :)

Comment: each menuItem object

Comment: I completed the answer with some code. the var dirToLookAt should give you the direction the menuItem.lookAt needs. Why did you use child to set the lookAt?

Comment: Thanks it's kind of doing the same thing as lookAt(camera.position) I've updated the CodePen http://codepen.io/bknill/pen/BLOwLj?editors=0010

Comment: I do not find the codepen.io run to check my changes. Can you try with menuItem.lookAt(camera.rotation) or menuItem.rotation.set(camera.rotation).

Comment: Thanks neither of those are making any difference. I'm making these changes in buildMenu() when the menuItems get added to the menu Object3D.